# How to filter list of list of rules on certain condition?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

For example, Solve[] returns all solutions as a list of list of rules. And mine looks something like this:

```
 { {g[2] -> g[1], g[3] -> 0, h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0}, 
   {g[1] -> 0, g[2] -> -Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, h[2] -> -Sqrt[2] h[3], h[4] -> (g[4] h[3])/g[3]}, 
   {g[1] -> 0, g[2] -> -Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0, h[4] -> 0}, 
   {g[1] -> 0, g[2] -> Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, h[2] -> Sqrt[2] h[3], h[4] -> (g[4] h[3])/g[3]}, 
   {g[1] -> 0, g[2] -> Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0, h[4] -> 0}, 
   {g[1] -> -2 Sqrt[2] g[3], g[2] -> -3 Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0, h[4] -> 0}, 
   {g[1] -> 2 Sqrt[2] g[3], g[2] -> 3 Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0, h[4] -> 0}, 
   ...... }
```

I want to select all list of rules in which both g[1] and h[3] don't go to 0. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The question is unclear, e.g. in the first list there is no limit for `g[1]`. P.s. Take a look at `Select` and `ReplaceAll`.

Comment: `Select` seems a good candidate. Try in combination with `FreeQ`

Comment: @Kuba Thank you. To make it clear, my intention is to select those that didn't assign values or assigned non-zero values or assigned a relation to other variables for g[1], h[3], etc.

Comment: So you want to remove all that contain `g[1] -> 0` and `h[3] -> 0` at the same time. Only one would be OK as well as the appearance of `g[1]` and `h[3]` in other relations. Is that right?

Comment: @mikuszefski I actually want both of them not go to zero as stated in the original question. But this is not important because if there's a way to apply one constraint( and people here showed me many =P ), I can always apply multiple constraints along with any logic as I want.

Comment: that is true... looking forward to see your favourite answer; plenty to chose from.

Comment: Thanks for the Accept.  I guess I read the question correctly after all. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yet another answer:

```
Pick[sols, FreeQ[#, 0, 1] & /@ ({g[1], h[3]} /. sols)]
```

Where `sols` is your `Solve` result.

Answer (score 2):

```
    rules = {{g[2] -> g[1], g[3] -> 0, h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0}, {g[1] -> 0, 
   g[2] -> -Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, h[2] -> -Sqrt[2] h[3], 
   h[4] -> (g[4] h[3])/g[3]}, {g[1] -> 0, g[2] -> -Sqrt[2] g[3], 
   h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0, h[4] -> 0}, {g[1] -> 0, g[2] -> Sqrt[2] g[3],
    h[1] -> 0, h[2] -> Sqrt[2] h[3], 
   h[4] -> (g[4] h[3])/g[3]}, {g[1] -> 0, g[2] -> Sqrt[2] g[3], 
   h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0, h[4] -> 0}, {g[1] -> -2 Sqrt[2] g[3], 
   g[2] -> -3 Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0, 
   h[4] -> 0}, {g[1] -> 2 Sqrt[2] g[3], g[2] -> 3 Sqrt[2] g[3], 
   h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0, h[4] -> 0}};

Delete[rules, 
     Join[Position[rules, g[1] -> 0], Position[rules, h[3] -> 0]]]

    (* {{g[2] -> g[1], g[3] -> 0, h[1] -> 0}, {g[2] -> -Sqrt[2] g[3], 
      h[1] -> 0, h[2] -> -Sqrt[2] h[3], 
      h[4] -> (g[4] h[3])/g[3]}, {g[2] -> -Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, 
      h[4] -> 0}, {g[2] -> Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, h[2] -> Sqrt[2] h[3], 
      h[4] -> (g[4] h[3])/g[3]}, {g[2] -> Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, 
      h[4] -> 0}, {g[1] -> -2 Sqrt[2] g[3], g[2] -> -3 Sqrt[2] g[3], 
      h[1] -> 0, h[4] -> 0}, {g[1] -> 2 Sqrt[2] g[3], 
      g[2] -> 3 Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, h[4] -> 0}}  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks, but deleting the rules from the the list to make them such that they  don't contain g[1] -> 0 and h[3] -> 0 is not what I wanted. I meant to select all the lists which don't contain g[1]->0 in the first place.

Comment: Then you formulate incorrectly, since it is not what stays in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Your example solutions plus some which don't have either g[1] or h[3] going to zero:

```
sol = {{g[2] -> g[1], g[3] -> 0, h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0}, {g[1] -> 0, 
    g[2] -> -Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, h[2] -> -Sqrt[2] h[3], 
    h[4] -> (g[4] h[3])/g[3]}, {g[1] -> 0, g[2] -> -Sqrt[2] g[3], 
    h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0, h[4] -> 0}, {g[1] -> 0, 
    g[2] -> Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, h[2] -> Sqrt[2] h[3], 
    h[4] -> (g[4] h[3])/g[3]}, {g[1] -> 0, g[2] -> Sqrt[2] g[3], 
    h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0, h[4] -> 0}, {g[1] -> -2 Sqrt[2] g[3], 
    g[2] -> -3 Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0, 
    h[4] -> 0}, {g[1] -> 2 Sqrt[2] g[3], g[2] -> 3 Sqrt[2] g[3], 
    h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0, h[4] -> 0}, {g[1] -> 1, 
    h[3] -> 1, g[2] -> 0}, {h[3] -> 1}};
```

Using `Select` and `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) as @kuba suggested:

```
Select[sol, ({g[1], h[3]} /. #) != {0, 0} &]
```

> {{g[1] -> 1, h[3] -> 1, g[2] -> 0}, {h[3] -> 1}}

Comment: Thank you, the answer is helpful. But this doesn't work with cases where g[1] is not assigned a value. I would want to keep those list, but Select doesn't admit them because (I presume) as g[1] is not assigned a value, it could be 0.

Comment: @Xilin My final example rule set does not include a rule for `g[1]` yet it is returned by my `Select` expression so I do not agree with your comment.

Comment: I tried `Select[Join[
  solution, {{g[1] -> 1, h[3] -> 1, 
    g[2] -> 0}, {h[3] -> 1}, {g[1] -> 2 g[2], 
    h[2] -> 1}}], ({g[1], h[3]} /. #) != {0, 0} &]`, and it only gives me `{{g[1] -> 1, h[3] -> 1, g[2] -> 0}, {h[3] -> 1}}`  Somehow while it admits your last example, it doesn't admit my new example. It just seems my guess about why it's behaving this way is wrong...

Answer (score 2):

```
solns = {
  {g[2] -> g[1], g[3] -> 0, h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0}, 
  {g[1] -> 0, g[2] -> -Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, h[2] -> -Sqrt[2] h[3], 
   h[4] -> (g[4] h[3])/g[3]}, 
  {g[1] -> 0, g[2] -> -Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0, h[4] -> 0}, 
  {g[1] -> 0, g[2] -> Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, h[2] -> Sqrt[2] h[3], 
   h[4] -> (g[4] h[3])/g[3]}, 
  {g[1] -> 0, g[2] -> Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0, h[4] -> 0}, 
  {g[1] -> -2 Sqrt[2] g[3], g[2] -> -3 Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0, 
   h[4] -> 0}, 
  {g[1] -> 2 Sqrt[2] g[3], g[2] -> 3 Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0, 
   h[4] -> 0}
};

DeleteCases[solns, {___, g[1] -> 0, __, h[3] -> 0, ___}]
```

> ```
>  {{g[2] -> g[1], g[3] -> 0, h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0}, 
>   {g[1] -> 0, g[2] -> -Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, h[2] -> -Sqrt[2] h[3], 
>    h[4] -> (g[4] h[3])/g[3]}, 
>   {g[1] -> 0, g[2] -> Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, h[2] -> Sqrt[2] h[3], 
>    h[4] -> (g[4] h[3])/g[3]}, 
>   {g[1] -> -2 Sqrt[2] g[3], g[2] -> -3 Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0, 
>    h[4] -> 0}, 
>   {g[1] -> 2 Sqrt[2] g[3], g[2] -> 3 Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0, 
>    h[4] -> 0}}
> ```

Comment: Is it right that this requires at least one element between `g[1]` and `h[3]` (the middle `__` a typo? `->___`) and (knowing how *Mathematica* sorts things probably OK) that they appear in that order?

Comment: I see that you interpreted the question is meaning *both* `g[1] -> 0` and `h[3] -> 0` must be present in a sublist for it to be removed?  I interpreted that if *either* were present it should be removed.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Yes, because OP wrote "both g[1] and h[3] don't go to 0" in the question. Needs disambiguating parentheses, I guess, but English doesn't have that feature. Wish it did.

Comment: @mikuszefski. I thought about using `___` , but decided I could get away with just `__`. It's certainly OK for the posted example. Only OP knows for sure the requirements of the real data.

Answer (score 1):

That would be my version:

```
rules = {
    {g[2] -> g[1], g[3] -> 0, h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0}, 
    {g[1] -> 0, g[2] -> -Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, h[2] -> -Sqrt[2] h[3], 
   h[4] -> (g[4] h[3])/g[3]}, {g[1] -> 0, g[2] -> -Sqrt[2] g[3], 
   h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0, h[4] -> 0}, {g[1] -> 0, g[2] -> Sqrt[2] g[3],
    h[1] -> 0, h[2] -> Sqrt[2] h[3], 
   h[4] -> (g[4] h[3])/g[3]}, 
    {g[1] -> 0, g[2] -> Sqrt[2] g[3], 
   h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0, h[4] -> 0}, 
    {g[1] -> -2 Sqrt[2] g[3], 
   g[2] -> -3 Sqrt[2] g[3], h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0, 
   h[4] -> 0}, {g[1] -> 2 Sqrt[2] g[3], g[2] -> 3 Sqrt[2] g[3], 
   h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0, h[4] -> 0}};

newRules=Select[rules,!(!FreeQ[#,g[1] -> 0]&&!FreeQ[#,h[3] -> 0])&]
```

...had to play with "logic", though. Hence the negations `!`.