# How to disqualify a rule

Tags: assumptions, rule

Executing this line

```
Assuming[x < 0, x -> 10]
```

Expected output:

> False

Say `x -> 10` is a root of a polynomial expression that I obtained from `Solve`. I'm getting tired of retyping it as:

```
Reduce[x < 0 && x == 10]
```

> False

Also, why does `Refine[x < 0 && x == 10]` not work? I thought that's what `Refine` does -- refines sets.

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to accomplish. Why not add desired restriction(s) (what I *think* you're trying to do) into `Solve`? As for `Refine`, perhaps revisit the documentation - the output is expected for your input.

Comment: Funny that `Refine[x < 0 && x == 10, x \[Element] Reals]` works.

Comment: @ciao: OK say we have: Solve[ a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x, Reals]. How do I restrict "x" to be x < 0? I'll have to take {{x -> -b + ...(* etc \*)}, {x -> -b - ...(* etc \*)}} then retype them as x == -b + ...(* etc \*) || x == -b - ...(* etc \*) && x < 0.

Comment: For Mathematica, `x -> 10` has no mathematical meaning, so functions such as `Refine` or `Simplify` will not do anything with it.  Rules are for use in `Replace` or `ReplaceAll`.  `->` is not comparable to `==`.  You can use structural (not mathematical) operations to filter rule lists, based on `Select`, `Cases`, etc.

Comment: You can add those inequalities to the system of equations you are solving, and switch to `Reduce`, e.g. `Solve[x < 10 && a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x, Reals]`.  Please use backticks to delimite bits of code in comments.

Comment: @szabolcs: Yeah I kinda had a the impression that the type "rule" was just an immediate solution that seemed like a good and original idea used together with /.

Comment: This format is very useful for substituting variables.  E.g. solve, `sol = Solve[equation, x]`, verify, `equation /. sol`.  Or put the result into a new equation without having to set explicit values to symbols.  Ref: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ManipulatingEquationsAndInequalitiesOverview.html

Comment: Still, "Rules" really don't have much purely mathematical equivalents and it shows with it's awkwardness when being used with other built-in functions in Mathematica.

Comment: @szabolcs: Solve[x < 10 && a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x, Reals] Oh yeah, I can... I guess it didn't pop up in my head because I didn't want to put too much constraint to Solve that it will not recognize a simple quadratic equation. As I observed that for certain cubic equations, it was starting to use the Root function. I thought I'd just keep on filtering it with Refine after the Solve was done with it.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: A slight generalization might improve the question: What if you had a solution set from `Solve` and wanted to repeatedly select rules according to different conditions?  Computing `Solve` only once is certainly to be desired, would come after.  (Caveat: I haven't checked whether this has been asked before.)

Comment: Somewhat related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86821/how-to-filter-list-of-list-of-rules-on-certain-condition

Comment: Why not `x < 0 /. x -> 10`?  The result of that seems to be what you expected to get with your first bit of code.  In general `Simplify[condition /. rules]` will check whether a solution satisfies a `condition`. `Simplify` may or may not be necessary depending on the complexity of the problem.

Comment: Close-voters may not see this at the end of the comment queue, but I don't see how this can be closed as a simple mistake etc., when I still find the question unclear.  I'm on my second guess already.  My first suggested clarification, based on some of the discussion with @Szabolcs, has been passed over without comment by the OP.  I could understand voting to close as unclear, but the second question about `Refine` not working seems perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

> Assuming[assum,expr]
>   evaluates expr with assum appended to $Assumptions, so that assum is included in the default assumptions used by functions such as Refine, Simplify, and Integrate.

As `x -> 10` (or even `x == 10` if `x` isn't assigned an explicit value) does not evaluate to anything, but itself, you shouldn't expect `Assuming` to change anything. This is slightly counterintuitive, but such is the case. The reason is, that `Equal` does not have an `Assumptions` option for `Assuming` to append the assumptions to wherever.

`Refine` is also similar in its counterintuitivity. If you don't pass an assumption to it, it has nothing to substitute `x` with to test the boolean expressions under these assumptions and also leaves them unevaluated.

As you said you're solving some polynomials and getting lists of rules, I'll allow myself to *make some assumptions* (pun totally intended) and offer a piece of example code.

```
sol = Solve[x^2 - 1 == 0, x]
(* {{x -> -1}, {x -> 1}} *)
Assuming[x < 0, Refine[Thread[x == (x /. sol)]]]
(* {x == -1, False} *)
```